# Callback when method finished

Tags: javascript, prototype, callback

I want to execute method: `bar()` when method `foo()` is done.

This could be done like this:

```
function foo() {
  //....
  bar();
}
```

But there is surely some way to execute `bar()` like a callback to `foo()`? I have been looking in prototype API, but so far I only found ways to bind callbacks to HTML-elements...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function foo(callback) {
   // ...
   callback();
}
```

And then you call foo like this:

```
foo(bar);
```

Comment: you might also want to check typeof callback to ensure it's a function

Comment: Thanks, whats the syntax when doing this inside of class created with Class.create();

Comment: Or another way - inside of function foo, assign callback = callback || function() {}; that way if callback is null or undefined, an empty function will be assigned and executed instead.